# Teradata SQL query to find sum of fields with same column values

Tags: sql, teradata

I really stuck with one task.
I have a table like this

```
Departure | Arrival    | SUM
 AAA      | ZZZ        | 100
 ZZZ      | AAA        | 50
 AAA      | CCC        | 60
```

I want get the sum of the same routes and  condition here is that I should treat AAA-ZZZ and ZZZ-AAA route as one route. The route ZZZ-AAA it's just route back from the original destination.

I'm trying to obtain the result like this:

```
Departure | Arrival    | SUM
 AAA      | ZZZ        | 150
 AAA      | CCC        | 60
```

Any suggestions, ideas please on how can I write my sql query to achieve that ?

Regards,
Jack

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] so that we can fiddle with it.  This means `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table and `INSERT INTO` statements to fill it with sample data.

Comment: Must this return an existing combination? I.e. in your example there's only `AAA,CCC`, is `CCC,AAA` a valid result, too? Then  Gordon's answer will fail.

Comment: Hi dnoeth,
Thanks for your comment.
CCC-AAA is not a valid result as in this case there is no such a route combination in the original table (source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(Departure, Arrival) as Departure,
       greatest(Departure, Arrival) as Arrival,
       sum(al)
from t
group by least(Departure, Arrival),
         greatest(Departure, Arrival);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
That's working perfectly for me and solve my problem.

Thank you very much for your quick response.

Regards,
Jack

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve to order of columns (i.e. `a,b` but no `b,a` must return the existing combination) you must expand Gordon's solution and add an indicator for the original order.

```
SELECT
    -- MIN(flag) = 1 -> departure < arrival
    --           = 2 -> arrival > departure or both exist
   CASE WHEN Min(flag)=1 THEN #1 ELSE #2 END AS departure,
   CASE WHEN Min(flag)=2 THEN #1 ELSE #2 END AS arrival,
   Sum(sumcol)
FROM
 (
  SELECT
    Least(Departure, Arrival) AS #1,
    Greatest(Departure, Arrival) AS #2,
    sumcol, -- seems this is already result of an aggregation?
    CASE WHEN departure < arrival THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS flag
  FROM nodupes  
 ) t
GROUP BY #1,#2;
```

This could be further simplified without Derived Table, but then it's really hard to understand and it's the same Explain anyway.